# setInterval running for some loops even after clearInterval of javascript

Tags: javascript, tracking

I am using tracking.js for facedetection and sending the result of facedetection to server through websocket. In the following code in if(event.data.length != 0) of setInterval  runs for some iterations even after clearInterval command.Could anyone explain why is it happening?

```
var mainfunc =  setInterval( function() {
     ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);

     tracking.track('#canvas', tracker);
     tracker.on('track', function(event){
         if (event.data.length != 0 ){
             var center_x = event.data[0].x + (event.data[0].width/2);
             var center_y = event.data[0].y +(event.data[0].height/2);    
             var str = center_x + " " + center_y +" " + center_image_x + " " + center_image_y + " " + flag ; 
             webSocket.send( str ); 
             // dunno why it is executing number of times ??????????

             clearInterval(mainfunc);   
         } 
    });
 } , 0);
```

Comment: If you have 2 unrelated questions, ask 2 questions. Otherwise you can't accept an answer. I'm removing the `websocket.sent` part, ask that separately.

Comment: Maybe try using timeout greater then 0. For example 1.

Comment: Please note that you can't set interval of 0. The minimum interval on browsers is 4 and 1 on Node.js. 0 is not supported by any JS engine now.

Comment: you might want to move to a tail-calling setTimeout, to run the code every interval not counting tasktime.

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason you're getting multiple executions is that your code is registering *"many"* event handlers inside the interval callback (`tracker.on(...` happens in every callback). Then, only when that event arrives with the condition satisfying data do you clear the interval. That's probably a basic flaw in your logic that should be changed. Only register to the 'track' event 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a missunderstanding how tracking and the setInterval functions.

setInterval is meant to run a piece of code over and over again with a set interval (in milliseconds).

According to the tracking.js' website, you only start the tracking once and it'll keep tracking things.

Try changing your code to this:

```
var trackerTask = tracking.track('#canvas', myTracker);

myTracker.on('track', function(event){
     if (event.data.length != 0 ){
         var center_x = event.data[0].x + (event.data[0].width/2);
         var center_y = event.data[0].y +(event.data[0].height/2);    
         var str = center_x + " " + center_y +" " + center_image_x + " " + center_image_y + " " + flag ; 
         webSocket.send( str ); 

         trackerTask.stop(); // stopping the tracking
     } 
 });
```

And now I'm not certain but I think you want to continously draw the video feed. You can do this in this way:

```
function drawVideo() {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo); //this will make sure it's redrawn as soon as the browser is ready
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
}

drawVideo(); //this call is needed to initiate drawing of the video.
```